# Finding the limit of a Matrices determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The problem is as follows:

[image]

I've been trying to figure this out with no luck. I'm lost at the $A_k+1$ and $A_0$. I'm not sure what they are implying and how they would apply in finding the limit.

Comment: It means: use the given recursive formula to calculate $A_3$. Then calculate its determinant $d=\det A_3$. Then calculate its inverse $d^{-1}$. Now $d^{-1}$ is a constant and you need to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} d^{-n}$. There isn't any trick here (although there is a slightly faster way to calculate $A_1$ than to apply the recursive formula directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it can be easily shown that

$$
A^{-1} \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
2 & -1\\
-1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

This implies that

$$
A_1 \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
3/2 & 0 \\
0 & 3/2 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

Implying that

$$
A_2 \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
3/4 & 0 \\
0 & 3/4 \\
\end{array} \right ] + \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
1/3 & 0 \\
0 & 1/3 \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
13/12 & 0 \\
0 & 13/12 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

Implying that

$$
A_3 \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
13/24 & 0 \\
0 & 13/24 \\
\end{array} \right ] + \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
6/13 & 0 \\
0 & 6/13 \\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{cc}
313/312 & 0 \\
0 & 313/312 \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

Therefore we have $A_3^{-1} = \frac{312}{313}I$, and thus $\det(A_3^{-1})^n = \left (\frac{312}{313}\right )^{2n}$ which tends to zero as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $A_1=\frac{3}{2}I$, so $A_2=\frac{13}{12}I$, so $A_3=\frac{313}{312}I$, and $A_3^{-1}=\frac{312}{313}I$. Hence its determinant is between 0 and 1, so the limit is 0.

Comment: I only saw your answer once I had posted mine, yours is very succinct.

Comment: Yes, it is infuriating when that happens. I would leave yours up, mine may be too succinct for the OP!